# Getting error like, #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

Here, I am getting error of `"#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row"` in query.

I found to use `IN` or `= ANY` to get multiple rows. But still I am getting error. 
Where I am getting false for this?

```
SELECT 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(image_view_count) 
        FROM tbl_image AS ti 
        WHERE ti.image_sub_category = tsc.sub_category_id) AS co,
        (
            SELECT image_thumb
            FROM tbl_image AS ti1
            WHERE ti1.image_sub_category = tsc.sub_category_id AND
                  ti1.image_view_count IN
                  (
                      SELECT MAX(image_view_count)
                      FROM tbl_image
                      WHERE tbl_image.image_sub_category = tsc.sub_category_id)) AS img2,
            tsc.*
FROM tbl_sub_category_reference AS tsc
JOIN tbl_sub_category AS sc
    ON sc.sub_category_id = tsc.sub_category_id
WHERE tsc.language_id = '2'
ORDER BY co DESC LIMIT 0,18446744073709551615
```

Comment: The `SELECT image_thumb` subquery is probably the cause of the error.  For a quick fix you could just add `LIMIT 1` to the end of the query, but really you should fix your logic.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : Yeah I thought like that but though I just want to know if I am wrong anything in this query. Btw thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It is more than a suggestion, it is the likely culprit.